# search criteria for mysql

Tags: java, mysql

Suppose I have a URL which consist of 3 parameters(A,B,C) where the client can send me any of the parameters as null or all can be null.

Now I need to find a way to retrieve records if the parameters are not null.

Suppose A is not null retrieve based on A.If B is not null retrieve based on B. If C is not null retrieve based on C.

Or

If A and B is not null retrieve based on A and B

(something like `where A='something' AND B='something'`).

If A and C is not null retrieve based on A and C. If C and B is not null retrieve based on C and B. 
or

If everything is not null retireve based on that`( means like where A='something' AND B='something' AND C='something')`

**Now one way I can do is create a lot of switch case other ways is using mysql query like this**

```
SELECT a.*,l.* FROM TabelA a INNER JOIN TableL l ON a.A= l.A WHERE
(
 a.A= IFNULL(NULL,a.A) AND
 a.B= IFNULL(NULL,a.B) AND
 a.C= IFNULL(NULL,a.C)
)
```

**Is there any other ways apart from these two ways**

Comment: There is one excellent way - don't do logic in MySQL. Since you tagged it with `Java`, you can do this logical argument parsing in java and then just query MySQL with what you produced.

Comment: By logical argument passing you mean check the variables which are not null and construct thw query accordingly? If that is what you mean then if the number of parameters increases then just think the numbers of condition checking i need to do

Comment: That's what I mean and if you do it programmatically then you don't have to care whether it's 1 or 100000 arguments being passed. That's why we have all these programming languages at our disposal. We have to figure out a pattern and have computers do hard work for us.

Comment: ok can u provide me some java example except using switch case

Comment: Nope, you don't appear to be someone who has to be spoonfed. I just provide concepts, not implementations. It's not difficult to obtain a URL, parse it to desired format and then loop through the parameters, check whether they satisfy your condition and if yes - add them to stack / list / whatever, is it? :)

Comment: I guess you dint read my question fully `Is there any other ways apart from these two ways`

Comment: @N.B. parsing is not even an issue the thing is I don't even know which will be null in the url or just imagine the numbers of times I need to check for null for the parameters and the number of conditions it will generate

Answer (score 0):

```
String query="SELECT a.*,l.* FROM TabelA a INNER JOIN TableL l ON a.A= l.A WHERE 1=1";
if (param1){
   query+=" AND Something="+param1;
}
...
```